# What is the 'right' way to form a row of elements? ul/divs?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a horizontal row of elements that form a panel of steps the user needs to take. These are all made out of blue rectangles that contain a title, text and an icon. See image for example.

[image]

I need the items to break at either 2 or 3 items depending on the screen size.

This can be achieved in (afaik) 2 ways.

- A div container with 6 divs, that all have their own class to help them beak at mobile sizes.
- an unordered horizontal list, with classes on the list items to help them break where I want.

How do I determine what is the 'right' option here? What method do I choose? Or does it really not matter?

Comment: There are lots of possible ways, what's "right" for each solution will vary and is largely opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Go For Lists(li) not div.**

If just getting the layout is the concern, You can use either div or li.

But I would prefer li over div since it looks like a list of things to me.
Thus to keep my code **semantic**, I will go for lists. HTML has the ability to express lists of things, and it helps the Google robot, screen readers, and all other devices that does not rely on the presentation of the site understand your content better.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that you have a step-by-step template, you can easily use an ordered list as a container. `ol > li(1/6%) > h3 + img + p`

Answer (score 0):

- There's no default HTML element with the styling you want.
- You will have to restyle some arbitrary other element to achieve what you want.
- It doesn't really matter which element you use as a starting point to create the style you want.
- The only difference therefore is a semantic one at the HTML level; what would be the most useful representation of the content without any style at all, purely from its **meaning**…?

I think it should be obvious that an **ordered list** carries the most useful semantics to mark up a list of steps which must be followed in order.

Answer (score 0):

If your using bootstrap you can use code below , otherwise you can use (li list) its more easy to right css.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-center">
      image-1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-center">
      image-2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-center">
      image-3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-center">
      image-4
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-center">
      image-5
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-center">
      image-6
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```